# How can I create Input field over full screen, image slideshow

Tags: html, image, css, background

I made the background of my page into a slideshow that cycles a series of images but I want to be able to display fields on top. How do I stop the fields from going behind the images?

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<header>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Playcation 2013</title>
<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/modernizer.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/index.css">
</header>
 <body id="page">
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
        <ul class="cb-slideshow">
           <li><span>Image 01</span><div></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 02</span><div></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 03</span><div></div></li>
            <li><span>Image 04</span><div></h3></div></li>
        </ul>
   </body>
```

CSS

```
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0; 
}
.cb-slideshow:after { 
    content: '';
    background: transparent url(../images/pattern.png) repeat top left; 
}
.cb-slideshow li span { 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s; 
}
.cb-slideshow li div { 
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing z-index to a negative value did it :)